# Yii composer dependencies not updating

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'm having a problem trying to update my composer dependencies for my Yii project. I currently have the minimum-stablity set to "stable".

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

If anyone can suggest anything that would be great.

What I have tried

- I have removed the vendor directory and reinstalled the dependencies.
- I have removed the packages from my composer.json file and attempted
  to update.

Problem:

```
Me-MacBook-Pro:ETS-Yii2 me$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for abhishek/authorize.net-yii2 * -> satisfiable by abhishek/authorize.net-yii2[dev-master].
- Removal request for abhishek/authorize.net-yii2 == 9999999-dev
Problem 2
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui ~1.12.1 -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.4 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.3 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- Removal request for yiisoft/yii2-jui == 2.0.0.0-beta
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-jui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-jui[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.0-beta].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Composer.json file

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "^2.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "*",
    "vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "*",
    "abhishek/authorize.net-yii2": "*",
    "yurkinx/yii2-image": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
    "fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your `composer.json` file that leads to this error?

Comment: Edited above. Please review.

Comment: Try switch to asset packagist - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733105/5812455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using "config" in place of "extra" like bellow:

```
"config" : {
    "process-timeout" : 1800,
    "fxp-asset" : {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject" : {
            "setPermission" : [{
                    "runtime" : "0777",
                    "web/assets" : "0777",
                    "yii" : "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey" : [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "installer-paths" : {
            "npm-asset-library" : "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library" : "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues here:

1. For the `abhishek/authorize.net-yii2` package there is no stable release. Thus, you need to change the version constraint from `*` to `dev-master`.
2. Your second problem is that `yiisoft/yii2-jui` requires `bower-asset/jquery-ui` which is a virtual package. Virtual packages mean that Composer cannot select what package to install, but you as a user must decide which package provides the best implementation for a particular virtual package. I don't know anything about Yii so I cannot help you by making this decision, but you can see all the packages providing an implementation of `bower-asset/jquery-ui` at https://packagist.org/providers/bower-asset/jquery-ui. When you have solved this, you will see a similar issue with `yiisoft/yii2` requiring `bower-asset/jquery` which also is a virtual package.